# How do I integrate an XSLT processor in my Electron.js application?

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, cheerio

I am developing an Electron application which requires some behind the scene XML manipulation through XSLT.

First thing I did was to hit npm and github but it got complicated real quick (I must admit I'm new to programming, it's mostly an hobby for me). Pretty much every library requires compiling and have multiple options I don't even understand (static compiling, ecc, ecc) and I can't see how can this help me deliver cross platform applications when so many platforms may or not have the required dependencies such as libxml2 or libxslt.

Maybe I should use the xml processor of Chromium? Feels kinda limited since it should only support XSLT 1 and I heard Chrome has issues with XSLT processing.

Another alternative I thought of was to manipulate the xml differently, with some sort of library that can parse xml documents such as cheerio (basically server side jquery), this would require a much more complicate approach for the xml's dom manipulation tho than using xslt stylesheets.

Last thing I thought of was handling this by uploading the xml to a server and handle the transformation here (so the xslt process is not client side) and then send the xml back to the user, but this would require unpredictable amounts of work and a potentially painful experience for the user (what if the server needs to process multiple 100mb convertions each taking,e.g, 4 hours?).

Comment: look at my issue here, maybe it helps: [Transform XML String [not file!] with XSLT String in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54946208/3775957)

Answer (score 1):

What platforms do you need to run on?

Saxon-JS currently ships to run on the browser, but it can be made to run on Node.js with a bit of tweaking (the main reason we don't promote it is the absence of useful things like XML parsing and serialization that aren't needed on the browser; plus lack of testing).

The main limitation is that Saxon-JS is an XSLT run-time only; it requires the stylesheets to be compiled under the Saxon-EE product on the server.

Comment: OSX-Linux-Windows.

That's the very reason why I choose Electron in the first place.

As for Saxon it seems like it's not something I could really integrate in each client installation and would rely on internet connection to a central server. Plus, it seems like a paid product. Got nothing against paid products (I am developing one myself) but seems an overstretch for what I need (basically process the same xml files with the same xslt every time).

Comment: Actually it's quite a good fit for the "process the same xml files with the same xslt every time" scenario, since you only pay for the development license (or it comes free with oXygen), and once you've compiled the stylesheet you can deploy it as widely as you like without further cost.

Comment: I don't understand tho, where is the xslt processing done, on the server or on the client?

Comment: @Aquazi, to use Saxon-JS you need Saxon EE (exists as a Java and as a .NET version and comes for instance with XML IDEs like oXygen) to compile your XSLT to a SEF format you can then execute in a browser like Chromium where you have your HTML use the Saxon-JS Javascript library to execute the SEF. I am not quite sure how Electron works but I guess as it includes Chromium you should be able to use Saxon-JS inside your Electron app the same way you could use it with Chromium, that is by integrating the Saxon-JS library.

Comment: @MartinHonnen but that forces me to learn Java or .NET...I hoped I could make it in an easier way. Plus, I still don't understand if I can ship SaxonEE with my application to my customers.

Feels like a lot of trouble for a simple xml transformation. Kind of feel like converting the xml to json would handle this much easier.

Comment: Saxon EE has a command line interface you can use to compile an XSLT stylesheet into a SEF package, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/compiling.html, so you don't have to learn any Java or .NET. And your app as far as I understood your requirements so far does not need Saxon EE, it needs Saxon-JS to run your compiled SEF files against your XML input files. Whether you need all that "trouble" I don't know, you did not seem to be satisfied with the XSLT 1, libxslt based processor you have with Chromium.