# Transform XML String [not file!] with XSLT String in Node.js to HTML

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, electron

I have two strings.

The first one is a xml string, saved as a string, not from a file.
The second one is a string I load from a XSLT file with `fs.readFile(...)`.

I already tried using `libxslt` but can't install it via `npm` due to some errors about MSBuildTools and so on.

Are there any alternatives for `libxslt`? I already came across `xslt-processor`too, but it only accepts files as parameters.

EDIT 1:

to provide you an overview, the XSLT file and an example XML file (both handled as strings in the app) can be downloaded here:

- [Stylesheet in a ZIP File](http://www.hl7.at/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ELGA-Referenzystylesheet_V1.06.001.1.zip)
- [Example XML Files in a ZIP](https://hl7.at//wp-content/uploads/2017/11/20171108%20CDA%20Beispiele%202.06.2.zip)

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt? It works on input strings. Disclaimer: I have not used it.

Comment: tried it out now, got the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to load the XSLT document` - maybe the the XSL is to large....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow got a workaround for my problem:

1. I now use the `xth` library (install via npm: `npm i xth`)
2. import it into my function: `var xth = require('xth');`
3. put the xml String into a data URI: `var xml = 'data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(xmlString);`
4. the XSLT file is now not a String but the file: `var xsl = './../components/ELGA_Stylesheet_v1-0.xsl';`
5. Then, I just call the method xth as in the example at [xth - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xth)

   `1 xth(xml, xsl, function (html) {
   2    html = html.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
   3    html = html.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
   4   html = html.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
   5    openWindow(html);
   6 });`
6. the item `html` is the xslt transformed string, I had one final problem: in the `<script>` Tags of the output string, the symbols <,> and & were there as &lt;, &gt;, and &amp; which caused problems. lines 2 to 4 are the workaround for this issue

`openWindow(html)`is my own method to open the result string in a new electron window.

NOTE: one problem remains: as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54946393/3775957), navigation via # in `<a href=#id>` doesn't work, because Chromium doesn't allow navigation to top frame to data uri.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* not tested for the attached XML/XSLT.

You could use [`saxon-js`](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml):

```
const saxon = require("saxon-js");
const env = saxon.getPlatform();

const doc = env.parseXmlFromString(yourStringXSLT);
// monkey-patch to avoid a "Required cardinality of value of parameter $static-base-uri is exactly one; supplied value is empty" compile error
doc._saxonBaseUri = "file:///";

const sef = saxon.compile(doc);
// you can save and reuse the SEF for future transforms, if applicable

const resultStringXML = saxon.transform({
  stylesheetInternal: sef,
  sourceText: yourStringXML
});
```

This approach may not be perfect (esp. the `_saxonBaseUri` hack) - but I couldn't find anything better (for `saxon-js`) documented online (except for the `xslt3` command-line based approach).